# Local node doesn't see that many transactions?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, pending-transactions

Just to be clear, this is for binance smart chain not eth chain.  I'm running a local BSC node and I have a filter for pending transactions and this was working well as of a couple days ago, but for some unexplainable reason the amount of transactions totally plummeted.  It's seeing ~1/10th of what it used to.  When I revert to using a public node, I see roughly the amount of transactions that I used to.  I have ~100+ peers so I have no clue what could have changed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I tried these two providers,
https://www.quiknode.io/
and
https://nownodes.io

nownodes provide a free trial access, you need to contact the support to ket an api key

Comment: That does not answer the question. The question is about running a local full node.